# Angular 2 best practice: binding an object vs binding its properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Is it best for a child component to have inputs of an object's properties and change emitters, or to two-way bind to the object like so:

Example 1

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component [exampleInput]="object.val" 
                   (valueChanged)="updateObjectValue($event)">
  </child-component>
</parent-component>
```

vs Example 2

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component [(obj)]="object"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

where example 2's child component would handle the updateObjectValue logic.

In our code right now, a component like this currently has 4 inputs and 2 outputs, and if reducing to 1 property by binding it directly to the object is fine that'd be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with event emitters option as its the recommended way.
Kindly refer this 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

```
<parent-component>
     <child-component [exampleInput]="object.val"
        (valueChanged)="updateObjectValue($event)">
     </child-component>
</parent-component>
```